# Handling segfault within specific address range

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, c++14

Given the usual setup for catching `SIGSEGV` :

```
static void handler(int, siginfo_t *si, void*)
{
    printf("SIGSEGV at %p\n", si->si_addr);
}
struct sigaction sa;
sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL)
```

How can we catch only if `si_addr` exists with a specific range?

This would be ideal:

```
sa.sa_sigaction = [start, end](auto&& si){
    if (si->si_addr >= start && si->si_addr <= end) {
        // only then do things
    }
};
```

How can I make start and end available in handler, if possible without using global mutable state?

Comment: What about global immutable state? ;)

Comment: @melak47 Then it's not possible to assign `start` and `end` ?

Comment: How are `start` and `end` determined?  Do you change it at run time, or is it fixed?  If changed at run time, and accessed via a stateless function pointer, it is global (hence accessable via a function pointer) and mutable (becaues you can change it).  Something that a stateless function pointer can access is global (or static).  Something that can be changed is mutable.  In short, can you be very exact in what you are asking so it doesn't read "I want a red fruit that isn't red or a fruit?"  Maybe you actually want a piece of wood that looks red to a color blind person, but I cannot tell.

Comment: Signal handler tend to be C style functions.  Why not make a couple of static variables with a get/set function in the same file where the handler is defined?